# Pine Script: Problem of alerts with strategy using calc_on_every_tick/On and pyramiding=0

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a strategy with parameter calc_on_every_tick = ON and Pyramiding = 0 which buy Long with first strategy.order Id="Long0" and then if quote decrease under X% of "Long0", it would buy an other long position with strategy.order with a different id = "Long1" and repeat for 5 different levels of decreasing.

It's OK in Backtest but in real life, if pyramiding=0, there is no alert for the decreasing order Long1, Long2 ... only for the first order.
It's strange because it's OK on back test but not in real life. I know that with calc_on_every_tick it's different than in back test but if strategy.order for "Long1" is with a price at 0.916 of "Long0", even if the quote decrease more than 0.8 from the real buy price "Long0", there is no alert. And, as the Id are different, I don't understand why there is no order with pyramiding=0.
For me it's a bug with Pine Script?????
Do you have an idea to explain what was wrong?

Below is my code for the first decreasing order "Long1"
Thank you very much for your help

`

```
if strategy.opentrades == 1
    if close < strategy.opentrades.entry_price(0) * 0.916
        strategy.order("Long1", strategy.long, comment = "Entrée Long1", alert_message = array.get(messageEntreeLongP0, 1))
```

`

Understand if it's a problem of wrong coding, wrong understanding of Pine Script functions or if it's a BUG of Pine Script

Answer (score 0):

Pyramiding = 0 prevents you to have more than one open order, in your code it seems to work like a charm.
See https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy

> pyramiding (const int) The maximum number of entries allowed in the same direction. **If the value is 0, only one entry order in the same direction can be opened**, and additional entry orders are rejected

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but normally strategy.order isn’t affected by pyramiding parameter ; it’s only for strategy.entry. So my second Long order for decreasing quote would have been produce an alert.

Comment: did you try with value = 88 for a test ?

Comment: Thank you for your new answer. Yes I did it, not with 88 but with other values than 0 and it's OK. But an other time what is strange is that this parameter of pyramiding would not have to affect strategy.order

Comment: @ytahiti I agree with you. I think the most important is that your code is now working. Don't forget to accept the answer if it has helped you.